# Sorting image files using server modifed date. Not File EXIF modified

Tags: php, date, server, exif

I have been told to rewrite my question by Stackoverflow

I upload images mostly to a directory on my sever where my website is hosted. Via a program on my PC and a app on phone and that works a treat.

I have come across PHP scripts that shows all the images in the above folder and returns a basic gallery, and they all work to a point.

What I am hoping to achieve (it might not be possible) is list the images by the date they were added to the server. Not sorting from the EXIF modified date.

If it cant be done, so be it.

Best regards,

RT

PS At the moment I'm use PHP Gallery, its OK but does not quite achive the sorting requirement I would like.

Gallery here. https://www.sidingstudios.com/pix4web/index.php

Is it possible to display the contents of server folder (images) but sort by Last Modified ? using PHP

```
My very basic script:
<?php
$images = glob('img/*');

foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo '<img src="'.$image.'"><br>';
}
?>
```

Link its used on. https://www.sidingstudios.com/pix4web2/

Comment: Yes that is very easily doable. Before displaying the images, sort them by date added.

Comment: How do you do that in the code I'm trying to use ?  Is there a command for Date Added ? Thanks for answering.

Comment: You have included no code, I am not a mind reader.

Comment: Right. I found the code I'm using and get back to you. I think I found it on GitHub. Back soon. Thanks.

Comment: This what I'm using at the moment. https://phpphotogallery.com/       All I'm looking for is being able to tweak the code to sort as Date Added as you suggest.

Comment: Please check how to post questions on this site. The code in question needs to be posted and not say, "go here." That's not how this site works.

Comment: I got kicked in teeth last time asked this question with code. Cant win with the forum. I did have some basic code and I'll try and post that. Failing that, I'll request my account here gets deleted. But thanks for talking to me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will sort the images by last modified time

```php
$files = glob('img/*');

$output = [];

foreach ($files as $f) 
{
    $output[filemtime($f)] = $f;
}
ksort($output);
$images = array_reverse($output);

foreach ($images as $image) 
{
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '"><br />';
}
```

Comment: That works like a dream. Many thanks.  So I assume ksort is the answer. Thanks.  All I need to work out is how to resize the image a bit smaller when echoing to the screen. But I will try and suss that. The main issue was the sorting. Thanks  RT. https://www.sidingstudios.com/gal1/index.php    All in order as server date, Crossing,snowdrops, hotel, ducks and trees. Your a star, sorry if upset anyone here.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider marking this answer as the right one by clicking the check mark right below the voting buttons :) Thank you in advance!